# What's the commended way to organize and load svg files as part of an R package?

Tags: r, svg, ggplot2, r-package

I have an R package that generates a PDF and I'd like to include some external SVG images as part of the generated reports e.g. SVG country flags. What is the commended way to organize it i.e. where to place the external images by convention? e.g. `inst\extdata\svg` or? from the R package how do you access these files?

Assuming that the resource SVG image's path is accessible from my R package I would do the following ([using this excellent Rlogo.html article as reference](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Reports/Rlogo/Rlogo.html)):

```
library(grImport2)
library(ggplot2)

myImage <- readPicture("image.svg")
myImageGrob <- gTree(children=gList(pictureGrob(myImage)))

ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x=disp, y=mpg)) + annotation_custom(myImageGrob)
```

Comment: I would place them in inst/svg, which gets copied as svg/ when the package is built. But it seems wasteful to read and convert the files every time the package is used; I would therefore also save the data as an rda file containing a named list of all the images, that can just be loaded (cf ggflags with pngs)

Comment: I am more less new to writing R extensions, can you please make an answer including the detail on load efficiency etc. Thank you!

Comment: I'll leave it as a comment as I don't have much experience with this type of data in R packages to be released on CRAN. You may want to post on r-pkgs list, that's likely to yield more definitive answers.